# Mass data export from SQL Server to Excel in VB

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net, excel

I have some code that works for smaller data sets. I get an 'out of memory' error with the huge data sets I use though (800k rows, 25 columns). I was trying to figure out a way to change this to mass export column by column, or maybe split up sets of rows, instead of the whole thing at once.

Clearly it can't handle that much data. I couldn't figure out how to separate it out some. Any ideas? Thanks!

```vb
For Each dt As System.Data.DataTable In ds.Tables
        ' Copy the DataTable to an object array
        Dim rawData(dt.Rows.Count, dt.Columns.Count - 1) As Object

        ' Copy the column names to the first row of the object array
        For col = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            rawData(0, col) = dt.Columns(col).ColumnName
        Next

        ' Copy the values to the object array
        For col = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            For row = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                rawData(row + 1, col) = dt.Rows(row).ItemArray(col)
            Next
        Next

        ' Calculate the final column letter
        Dim finalColLetter As String = String.Empty
        Dim colCharset As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        Dim colCharsetLen As Integer = colCharset.Length

        If dt.Columns.Count > colCharsetLen Then
            finalColLetter = colCharset.Substring( _
             (dt.Columns.Count - 1) \ colCharsetLen - 1, 1)
        End If

        finalColLetter += colCharset.Substring( _
          (dt.Columns.Count - 1) Mod colCharsetLen, 1)

        ' Fast data export to Excel
        Dim excelRange As String = String.Format("A1:{0}{1}", finalColLetter, dt.Rows.Count + 1)
        excelSheet.Range(excelRange, Type.Missing).Value2 = rawData

        excelSheet = Nothing
    Next
```

Comment: EPplus is good solution for it. Have you tried it? If you are using excel object in .net then it will definitely give you outofmemory exception. Better try using some open source  dll. Please refer the link http://epplus.codeplex.com/. you may get an idea how it works! It uses the template file uploaded in your project and copy it to new one and dump the datatable in newly created excel file.

Comment: Any reason not to use an SSIS that you can run from code?

Answer (score 3):

Is there other code that manipulates the excel spreadsheet? If not, it would probably be faster to just write this out to a plane text file in CSV format. Excel will open the CSV and present it like a normal spreadsheet.

Comment: as of now, no there isn't. can't say i know how i would export as a csv but i will look into that.

Comment: It looks like he's expecting (or allowing for) multiple tables in the dataset. That would mean multiple csv files, where excel could do this all in one workbook.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn yes that may be the case, I was not sure about that. Also it may look like there is a potential error in your code above if there is more than one DataTable. You are setting excelSheet to Nothing, but you never re-create it upon next for loop. Do some searching around for sample code to write a CSV file from a DataTable in VB.Net, you will find many.